# append code to a macro in amsmath align environment

Tags: align, latex3

I want to append code to a macro in amsmath `align` environment. I tried `\g@addto@macro` and `LaTeX3` macro `\tl_gput_right:Nn`, but it seems double the code that I want to append.

Here is `MWE`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3,amsmath}

\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \gtmpatl
\def\tlgputright{\tl_gput_right:Nn} %\def\tlgputright{\g@addto@macro}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{align}\tlgputright\gtmpatl{hi}
 A &= B 
\end{align}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_show:N \ltmpatl
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

It shows `\gtmpatl=hihi`.

Answer (score 2):

The `align` environment typesets its argument twice: the first time for measuring, and the second time for printing. Your macro is thus executed twice. To check against this, the package `amsmath` has an internal boolean `\ifmeasuring@` which is true in the first (measuring) passage, and false in the second (printing) one.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\def\gtmpatl{}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\tlgputright}{\ifmeasuring@\expandafter\@gobbletwo\else\expandafter\g@addto@macro\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\texttt{\meaning\gtmpatl}
\begin{align}
\tlgputright\gtmpatl{hi}
A &= B 
\end{align}
\texttt{\meaning\gtmpatl}
\tlgputright\gtmpatl{-ho}
\texttt{\meaning\gtmpatl}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I learn something new every day (about `\ifmeasuring@`).